# How to write a `for` loop over bool values (false and true)

Tags: c++, for-loop, boolean

A question mostly for fun/curiosity: how to write a `for` loop in C++ that would iterate over two values of a `bool` (i.e. `true` and `false`), using only operations with `bool` (i.e. without conversions to other types)?

The background is that I wanted to check how many solutions exists for an equation like `(A && B) || (!B && !C && !D) == true`, and started to write something like `for (bool A=false; ??? ; ++A) for (bool B=false; ...)` etc but immediately got stuck by `???` - i.e. what would be the condition to continue the loop? Of course I rewrote it to use int, and I also know that a `do ... while` loop will work, but I got curious if it's ever possible to write such a `for` loop? And since SO does not seem to have an answer, I decided to ask :)

---

Update: note that an "obvious" variant `for(bool A=false; !A; A=true)` suggested in at least two now-removed answers will only run one iteration, because for the second one the condition `!A` becomes `false` and the loop ends.

After some pondering, I believe it's impossible to do it in C++03 without a second variable or a pointer based construct like suggested by Dietmar Kühl. The condition should be tested three times in a desired execution, so two values of a bool are simply not enough. And the do-while loop works because the first iteration is executed unconditionally, the condition is only checked twice and so a bool value can be used to select between continuing and exiting.

Comment: It is amazing how quickly the wrong answers get removed!

Comment: Yes, don't you hate it when they do this? I find it a fine question. I upvoted.

Comment: Because this site is not for fun/curiosity. Real questions! PS No, it wasn't me, I'm curious too.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question, as well as a fun curiosum. +1

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In C++11: `for (bool b : { false, true }) { /* ... */ }`

Here's a C++03 version:

```
for (bool a = true, b = false; b != a; a = a && b, b = !b) { /*...*/ }
```

(Use either `a` or `b`.)

Comment: That's an interesting version with the initializer list.

Answer (score 8):

When restricted to C++2003 you could use an approach roughly equivalent to the C++2011 approach;

```
{
  bool const bools[] = { false, true };
  for (bool const* it(bools); it != std::end(bools); ++it) {
      bool a(*it);
      use(a);
  }
}
```

Possibly packed up in a macro. You can also use

```
for (bool a: { false, true }) {
    use(a);
}
```

Comment: I think you could possibly pack that array into the declaration part of the for loop. Not sure though.

Comment: @Wolf: the response was written 2012. I guess, past me didn’t assume C++11 being generally available (although I discovered the necessary functionality to implement `std::end()` -1998.

Comment: Great you updated it :) and it will help me to remember `std::end` ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
  doStuff(a ? true : false);
```

And forget about "no conversions to other types" restriction :) In the end of the day clarity is more important than artificial restrictions. Five years down the line you'll be reading your own code and wondering "what the heck was I thinking, is this some sort of an obfuscation contest?"

Comment: If you use a `char`/`uint8_t` instead of an `int`, there's a good chance they'll compile into the same underlying datatype and give you zero-cost casting.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson It depends on `doStuff` whether `int` is efficient or not.

Comment: Or you could for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
  doStuff(a==1);

Answer (score 5):

```
a = true;
do {
  use(a);
  a = !a;
} while (!a);
```

OK, so it's not a *for* loop, but I would argue it is more readable than any of the for loop suggestions (other than the C++11 approach, of course.)

Comment: To make `continue` work inside the loop as expected: `a = false; do { ... } while (a = !a);`. Initial value in a variable/constant: `a = init; do { ... } while (init != (a = !a));`

Answer (score 2):

One more for C++03:

```
for(bool a = false, b = true; b; a = !a, b = a)
```

Use b.

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses the "impossible" C++03, single-variable only solution

First, let us confirm that no deterministic arithmetic expression relying only on a single input variable can be true for both inputs `true,false` but then not for a third value that must be one of `true` or `false`.

However, we can "cheat". Though, I'd implore you to prove I'm actually cheating.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (bool b = false; *((char*)&b) != 2; *((char*)&b) += 1) {
        cout << "bool " << b << endl;
    }
}
```

This certainly *seems* like undefined behavior. C++03 is a bit [unclear about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380742/is-it-safe-to-memset-bool-to-0?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, `sizeof` must always be at least 1 (with a non-standard exception for 0-length var-len arrays). Moreover, since we're guaranteed each char is at least 8 bits, we can use the second one for our counter.

Indeed, to do this we need to either skirt determinism (can't without giving up the guarantee we iterate over `false, true` exactly once) or our constraining type system.

Answer (score 1):

This one works, too:

```
for (bool a = false, b = false; a == b; b = !b, a = a || b) { }
```

(sort of inverted solution than @KerrekSB's)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a solution without conversion to other type, but I suppose you mean "without conversion to unappropriated other type". Here is an answer offering an object replacing `bool` in this specific case.

```
struct IterableBool
{
  bool b;
  bool out_of_scope;
  IterableBool() : b(false), out_of_scope(false) {}
  IterableBool(bool b_) : b(b_), out_of_scope(false) {}
  IterableBool(IterableBool ib) : b(ib.b), out_of_scope(ib.out_of_scope) {}
  operator bool () { return this->b; }
  bool in_scope() const { return !this->out_of_scope; }
  IterableBool& operator ++ ()
  {                    
    this->out_of_scope = this->b;
    this->b = true;
    return *this;
  }
  IterableBool operator ++ (int)
  {
    IterableBool copy = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return copy;
  }
  IterableBool& operator -- ()
  {
    this->out_of_scope = !this->b;
    this->b = false;
    return *this;
  }
  IterableBool operator -- (int)
  {
    IterableBool copy = *this;
    --(*this);
    return copy;
  }
};

// Usage :
for(IterableBool ib = false;  ib.in_scope(); ++ib)
  do_stuff((bool)ib);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly less confusing version for old school programmers, based on Pokrovsky's answer:

```
bool firstPass=true;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++, firstPass=false)
    myfunc(firstPass);
```

or more simply:

```
for (int pass = 1; i < 3; i++)
    myfunc(pass == 1);
```

or even

```
for (int secondPass = 0; secondPass < 2; ++secondPass)
    myfunc(!secondPass);
```

(which Pokrovsky's answer optimizes to).

I think it's important for the variable to make sense when a programmer sees it down in the loop.