# Loop over ALL the values

Tags: c++

This might be an odd question, but how does one nicely loop over ALL values of a type.  In particular the standard integral types such as `unsigned short`.  A normal `for` loop construct presents a difficulty: what condition to use to exit the loop - because all values are valid.

Of course, there are several ways to get the job done.  Exit on the last value then handle that after the loop.  Use a bigger int to count.  The question is, is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to brute-force something? Don't try this with a 64-bit integer though...

Comment: [Iterating over all unsigned integers in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432995/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a pretty solution you can do this:

```
for(auto x : everyvalue<short>()) {
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Where `everyvalue` is:

```
#include <limits>
template<typename T>
struct everyvalue {
  struct iter {
    T x;
    bool flag;
    inline iter operator++() {
      if(x == std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
        flag = true;
      else
        ++x;
      return *this;
    }
    inline T operator*() { return x;}
    inline bool operator!=(iter& i) {return flag != i.flag;}
    // note: missing some iterator requirements, still should work
  };
  inline iter begin() { return iter{std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),0}; }
  inline iter end() { return iter{std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),1}; }
};
```

Otherwise a simple `break` would be preferred.

Comment: I'm going to give this answer the big green tick.  The end result is elegant and generalised.  All the ugly stuff is done once, done right and hidden away, which is a big part of how C++ should be used (in my opinion).  Some of the other answers may have performance advantages, but that wasn't what I was after.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <limits>
int i = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
do {
    ...
    if(i == std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        break;
    i++;
} while(true);
```

This is in contrast to a for() statement which translates to:

```
#include <limits>
int i = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
while(true) {
    if(i == std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        break;
    ...
    i++;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I worried about this very same issue once, and this is the best I could think of:

```
unsigned char c = 0;
do
{
    printf("%d ", (int)c); //or whatever
} while (++c != 0);
```

One of the very few cases where I find the `do..while` syntax useful.

Note that technically it is only valid for unsigned types, as I am relying on the wrapping of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the value by which you increment with a flag to say you've reached the max so you don't increment past it:

```
for ( char i ( std::numeric_limits<char>::min() ), j ( 1 );
      i != std::numeric_limits<char>::max() || j--;
      i += j )
    std::cout << ( int ) i << '\n';
```

but only elegant as in 'sophisticated' rather than 'clean simple lines'.

Answer (score 0):

[Look up the minimum and maximum values?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/)

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. This has the same problem as the other (now-deleted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a larger type:

```
unsigned long i;
for (i = std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::min();
     i <= std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max();
     i++)
```

Comment: `i <= i != [...]`? Was that just meant to be `i <= [...]`?

Comment: +1 Of course, assuming `unsigned long` really is larger than `unsigned short`. It is on implementations I know of, but I'm just pointing it's not guaranteed.

Comment: True.  A check for appropriate type sizes would be a good idea.

Comment: This was one of the solutions I already suggested, but my issue with this approach is that you then have to cast i down to an unsigned short before you can use it.  Or you could maintain an additional variable of the right type.

Comment: @wxffles the cast is safe because you know for a fact that the value fits in the smaller type.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked the same question about bools: [How to write a `for` loop over bool values (false and true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805161/how-to-write-a-for-loop-over-bool-values-false-and-true). You may look for the answers there. I then realized that since a for-loop iterating over all possible values would need to evaluate the condition one more time, you need an extra value (in any form - a bigger type, a second variable, etc) to properly distinguish all cases. And, a do-while loop works for this case because it needs exactly as many comparisons as there are distinct values.