# Techniques for reinterpreting the bits of one type as a different type

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Note: This question started with a faulty premise: the values that appeared to be 0.0 were in fact very small numbers. But it morphed into a discussion of different ways of reinterpreting the bits of one type as a different type. TL;DR: until C++20 arrives with its new `bit_cast` class, the standard, portable solution is `memcpy`.

Update 3: here's a very short app that demonstrates the problem. The bits interpreted as `float` always give a value of 0.0000:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    uint32_t i = 0x04501234;  // arbitrary bits should be a valid float
    uint32_t bitPattern;
    uint32_t* ptr_to_uint = &bitPattern;

    volatile float bitPatternAsFloat;
    volatile float* ptr_to_float = &bitPatternAsFloat;

    do {
        bitPattern = i;

        memcpy( (void*)ptr_to_float, (const void*)ptr_to_uint, 4 );

        // The following 2 lines both print the float value as 0.00000
        //printf( "bitPattern: %0X, bitPatternAsFloat: %0X, as float: %f \r\n", bitPattern, *(unsigned int*)&bitPatternAsFloat, bitPatternAsFloat );
        printf( "bitPattern: %0X, bitPatternAsFloat: %0X, as float: %f \r\n", bitPattern, *(unsigned int*)&bitPatternAsFloat, *ptr_to_float );

        i++;

    } while( i < 0x04501254 );

    return 0;
}
```

(original post)

```
float bitPatternAsFloat; 
for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= 0xFFFFFFFF; i = (i & 0x7F800000) == 0 ? i | 0x00800000 : i + 1 ) 
    {
        bitPatternAsFloat = *(float*)&i;
...
```

The loop steps through every bit pattern, skipping those in which the `float` exponent field is 0. Then I try to interpret the bits as a `float`. The values of `i` look OK (printed in hex), but `bitPatternAsFloat` always comes back as 0.0. What's wrong?

Thinking that maybe `i` is held in a register and thus `&i` returns nothing, I tried copying `i` to another `uint32_t` variable first, but the result is the same.

I know I'm modifying the loop variable with the ternary in the `for` statement, but as I understand it this is OK.

Update: after reading about aliasing, I tried this:

```
union FloatBits { 
    uint32_t uintVersion;
    float floatVersion;
};
float bitPatternAsFloat;

// inside test method: 
union FloatBits fb;  // also tried it without the 'union' keyword

// inside test loop (i is a uint32_t incrementing through all values)
fb.uintVersion = i;
bitPatternAsFloat = fb.floatVersion;
```

When I print the values, `fb.uintVersion` prints the expected value of `i`, but `fb.floatVersion` still prints as 0.000000. Am I close? What am I missing? The compiler is `g++` 6, which allows "type punning".

Update 2: here's my attempt at using `memcpy`. It doesn't work (the float value is always 0.0):

```
uint32_t i = 0;
uint32_t bitPattern;
float bitPatternAsFloat;

uint32_t* ptr_to_uint  = &bitPattern;
float*    ptr_to_float = &bitPatternAsFloat;

do {
    bitPattern = i; //incremented from 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF
    memcpy( (void*)ptr_to_float, (const void*)ptr_to_uint, 4 );
    // bitPatternAsFloat always reads as 0.0
    ...
    i++;
    } while( i );
```

Comment: `*(float*)&i` is undefined behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991478

Comment: I have seen this construct used in other code. What's wrong with it? Get the address of `i`, cast is as a pointer to a `float`, and dereference the pointer. How else can I do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This is the solution, not the problem.  What problem are you trying to solve with this solution?

Comment: I want to interpret the bits of a `uint32_t` as a `float`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do in standard C++. If you've seen it in other code, you've seen it in dirty C hacks from the 80s that were running on a specific hardware target. But any manipulation like this is *non-portable*.

Comment: Yes, but *why* do you want to interpret the bits of a uint32_t as a float?

Comment: Manipulating/testing some custom hardware requires it. Not at liberty to give details.

Comment: better use `int i = 0; do { ...; i++; } while (i)` to [loop through all bit patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432995/995714)

Comment: Use `memcpy()` from pointer of `int` to pointer of `float`. And `i <= 0xFFFFFFFF` is always `true` for 32 bits

Comment: Good catch! `i <= 0xFFFFFFFF is always true for 32 bits`

Comment: @phuclv Thats UB due to signed integer overflow. You'd have to use an unsigned integer for that to work.

Comment: @Swordfish yes. forgot to change the type

Comment: @Swordfish I am using a uint32_t so it should work

Comment: I will suggest to add `__attribute__((packed))` after the union and verify `sizeof(union FloatBits)` is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @geza for pointing out that the "failures" were an artifact of `printf` not being able to show very small numbers in `%f` format. With `%e` format the correct values are displayed.

In my tests, all of the various conversion methods discussed work, even the undefined behavior. Considering simplicity, performance, and portability it seems the solution using a `union` is best:

```
uint32_t bitPattern; 
volatile float bitPatternAsFloat;

union UintFloat {
    uint32_t asUint;
    float asFloat;
} uintFloat;

do {
    bitPattern = i;  // i is loop index
    uintFloat.asUint = bitPattern;                               
    bitPatternAsFloat = uintFloat.asFloat;
```

An interesting question is whether the `float` member in the `union` should be declared `volatile`: it is never explicitly written, so might the compiler cache the initial value and reuse it, failing to notice that the corresponding `uint32_t` is being updated? It appears to work OK on my current compiler without the `volatile` declaration, but is this a potential 'gotcha'?

P.S. I just discovered `[reinterpret_cast][1]` and wonder if that's the best solution.

Comment: `union` trick causes undefined behaviour, regardless of `volatile`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Are you referring to the rule that reading a member of a union that is not the last member written is undefined? I don't understand this restriction as it seems to obviate much of the reason for using a `union`, and I can't actually think of a use case for it. Also, it seems many compilers (like mine) do allow this "type punning"(?)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, I thought of one use case: reusing a "scratchpad" area of RAM as temporary storage for different types of data, as a memory-saving tactic. Is that the whole official reason for the existence of unions?

Comment: *"reading a member of a union that is not the last member written [causes UB]"* Yes. `reinterpret_cast` solution leads to UB as well. AFAIK, the right thing is to use `memcpy`, and hope that compiler will optimize it away. In C++20 we'll have `std::bit_cast` for this purpose. *"use case for unions"* Assume you need to write a function that has to be able to return objects of different types, and you know all possible types in advance. You can return a union, along with `enum` that tells which field is currently active. (In C++ `std::variant` should be preferred, but it's a common trick in C.)

Comment: Some compilers indeed treat union type-punning as a well-defined thing. E.g. in GCC manual there is a remark saying that while it's technically undefined, it's so widely used that they decided to allow it.

Comment: Use `memcpy`. It is the best current (C++17) solution. Efficient, and well defined (this issue comes up a lot in SO, I think you can find a lot of information about this). reinterpret_cast is not different from C-style cast in this regard, it is UB as well.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the C++20 documentation states explicitly that `memcpy` is the workaround until `bit_cast` is available. Seems pretty likely that it would be slower than a simple cast of pointers, though.