# Loop over a Boolean

Tags: c++, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a `for` loop over bool values (false and true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805161/how-to-write-a-for-loop-over-bool-values-false-and-true)

I want to perform the same task twice with `bool flag` true first and false second. Is there an elegant way to do that (maybe using a loop)?

My idea was to do something like the following but this is a way too complicated.

```
bool flag = true;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i, flag = !flag)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a nice way using a do-while-loop.

```
bool flag = false;
do
{
    // ...
    flag = !flag;
}
while(flag)
```

Since the code in a do-while-loop is executed at least once, I can toggle the flag at the end and get exactly two runs.

Answer (score 5):

Put it in a function, taking `flag` as an argument. Call the function twice.

Comment: Definitely the right way! (Passing flag as an argument of course!

Comment: The simplest solution is the best. In my case I would have to pass many variables parameters so I tried avoiding a function for that. But if there is no better solution I would accept your answer.

Comment: @sharethis: If you have many related variables, it may be worth thinking about how they could be grouped together into a class.

Comment: I thought about that but is doesn't make sense in my case and in addition to that my code is strongly performance related.

Comment: Did you actually profile your code first? I highly doubt that the function call will make any difference.

Comment: You can always declare the function `inline` if your profiling reveals that it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said you'd have to pass a lot of parameters to the function in Thomas' answer, consider a lambda:

```
int param1;
bool param2;
...

auto doWork = [&](bool flag){ //<- capture all local variables by reference
    ... do work with params ...
};

doWork(true);
doWork(false);
```

This way you have your working code encapsulated, don't have to tediously pass any parameters and still have it obvious that you're calling code twice.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to call it in a function is probably best, but you can also do:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    bool flag = i == 0;
    ...
```